# Debian - all browsers jquery compressed breaks all js, but uncompressed works fine

Tags: jquery, debian

In debian linux when using a browser such as opera or chome the page loads with a js error. This does not happen in any other browser and in fact I cannot even reproduce it, but another user can reproduce it in almost every browser on his system.

The errors are:

```
[12/07/11 19:08:22] JavaScript - http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
Linked script compilation
Syntax error at line 2 while loading:
,"*":"*/**/*;q=0.01":""):d.accepts["*"])
--------------------^
expected '}', got ':'
[12/07/11 19:08:23] JavaScript - http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/index.php
Inline script thread
Uncaught exception: ReferenceError: Undefined variable: $
Error thrown at line 1, column 0 in http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/index.php:
    $(document).ready(function()
[12/07/11 19:08:33] JavaScript - http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js
Linked script compilation
Syntax error at line 2 while loading:
,"*":"*/**/*;q=0.01":""):d.accepts["*"])
--------------------^
```

This only happens when jquery is minified, it doesn't happen otherwise. This is mind boggiling.
[image: Error in SeaMonkey]

Comment: are you using the minified version provided from the JQuery site, or are you minifying it yourself? If its the latter, I'd suggest that you're probably using a faulty minifier.

Comment: right from the jquery website jquery-1.6.2-min.js

Comment: have you tried saving the copy that is served by your site, and saving a new copy direct from JQuery.org, and doing a diff to see if they really are the same?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. I had the person locally install the program (same javascript) and it worked fine. Could something over the network cause a problem?

Comment: hmm... are you using gzip compression? I can't think of much else.

Comment: How would I check if I am using gzip compression? would this be on the server side?

Comment: It would be in your apache config.

Comment: gzip compression is off, is there anything else you can think of?

Comment: Can you try http://demo.phppointofsalestaging.com and see if you can go to the items page and click "New Item" (It should open up in a model window on the same page)

Comment: went to page, navigated to items, clicked 'new item', popup box appeared as described. JQuery appears to be working fine.

Comment: The error is happening only in debian for one user I can't reproduce it. In the original post I have put the error.

Comment: for what it's worth, I'm browsing using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads-up...

http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10153#comment:2

> Your minifier is incorrectly seeing the /* inside a QUOTED string as
>   the beginning of a multi-line Javascript comment. PLEASE DO NOT TAUNT
>   HAPPY FUN JQUERY with a broken minifier; instead use the
>   properly-minified version available at code.jquery.com or any of the
>   CDNs.

- jQuery Bugs Team